# Python3 subprocess.Popen is failing to remove file with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error, but file is actually present

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Python3 subprocess.Popen is failing to remove the file with "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. **But executing the command directly from the bash terminal deletes the file.**

**current folder content:**

```
tmp]$ ll
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  688 Apr 29 09:28 t1.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  688 Apr 29 10:41 t2.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 1052 Apr 29 10:41 t3.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  364 Apr 29 10:45 t4.py
```

**Python Code (t4.py):**

```
  1 import subprocess
  2
  3
  4 def execute_shell_command(command_list):
  5     data = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  6     output = data.communicate()
  7     return output
  8
  9
 10 cmd = ["rm -rf ", "", "t2*"]
 11 command = cmd[0] + cmd[1] + cmd[2]
 12 prnt1 = "Executing command: " + command
 13 print(f"{prnt1}")
 14 out2 = execute_shell_command(command)
 15
```

**Output:**

```
tmp]$ python3 t4.py
Executing command: rm -rf t2*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t4.py", line 14, in <module>
    out2 = execute_shell_command(command)
  File "t4.py", line 5, in execute_shell_command
    data = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rm -rf t2*': 'rm -rf t2*'
```

Comment: use `cmd = ["rm", "-rf ", "t2*"]`

Comment: oh, yeah you're correct, each value separated by a comma should be a different element in the command_list!

Comment: This solution also didn't help. Not sure why!

The change i did is: 
`cmd = ["rm", "-rf ", "t2*"]`

The error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rm-rf t2*': 'rm-rf t2*'`

Answer (score 0):

**Below code worked:**

```
  1 import subprocess
  2
  3
  4 def execute_shell_command(command_list):
  5     data = subprocess.Popen(command_list, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  6     output = data.communicate()
  7     return output
  8
  9
 10 cmd = ["rm -rf t2*"]
 11 command = cmd[0]
 12 prnt1 = "Executing command: " + command
 13 print(f"{prnt1}")
 14 out2 = execute_shell_command(command)
 15 print(f"output = {out2[0]}")
 16 print(f"error = {out2[1]}")
```

Basically, write the command as it is and then add one argument **shell=True** in the *subprocess.Popen*.

Comment: This solution also didn't help. Not sure why!

The change i did is: 
`cmd = ["rm", "-rf", "t2*"]`

The error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rm-rft2*': 'rm-rft2*'`